# Focus a window without changing z-order

Tags: c, winforms, winapi

I have a somewhat hackish utility that sends keystrokes to a window, using `SendInput()`. That works just fine, however, the target window needs to be a foreground window, so before sending anything, the utility needs to call `SetForegroundWindow()`. This is annoying from the user's perspective, as the target window flashes to the top (even though the utility immediately switches back to the recent active window, so that the user can continue work).

Is there a way to focus a window, without changing z-order? I realise that it is not a common use case, as it would be extremely frustrating under normal conditions for the user to have a background window active, where they might not even see what they are typing. I tried using both `SetFocus()` and `SetWindowPos()` with `SWP_NOZORDER`, but neither of them actually activates the window.

Note that the window I'm trying to activate is not owned by the calling thread. Also note that I can't use `SendMessage()` as the keystroke is a `CTRL+NUMPAD3` combination and the target window will not react to separate `WM_KEYDOWN` / `WM_KEYUP` events, I've tried. It might be relevant that I'm trying to use this on Windows 7.

My code so far is:

```
HWND h_target = FindWindow(...);

INPUT p_input[2] = {0};
p_input[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
p_input[0].ki.wVk = VK_CONTROL;
p_input[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
p_input[1].ki.wVk = VK_NUMPAD3;
// prepare input

HWND h_act = GetForegroundWindow();
// remember this

SetForegroundWindow(h_target); // works
//SetWindowPos(h_target, HWND_TOP, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE); // does not work
// activate the target window first

SendInput(2, p_input, sizeof(INPUT));
// send the keystrokes

p_input[0].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
p_input[1].ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
SendInput(2, p_input, sizeof(INPUT));
// don't forget to release the keys

SetForegroundWindow(h_act);
// put the active window back
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at the return value of `SetWindowPos` to maybe see why that's not working? Also, I imagine it's not possible to make your target window be the "foreground" window whilst the user has some other actual foreground window. What exactly is the target window? If it doesn't respond to `WM_KEYDOWN`, it might be directly polling the keyboard state.

Comment: @DrewMcGowen From MSDN: "SetWindowPos function Changes the size, position, and Z order of a child, pop-up, or top-level window." so if it is not on top, it does nothing to it. The target window is a remote desktop terminal and yes, it polls `GetKeyState()` - that is why I need to use `SendInput()`, which correctly simulates that.

Comment: In Windows 95 days I used to use a little utility that let you send a window to the back by right-clicking the title bar, and the window would still stay active and receive keyboard input, so it's certainly possible for a window that's not at the top of the Z order to do this. It might be possible if you inject into the target process and handle `WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING` to clear the `hwndInsertAfter` field (or maybe other messages instead/as well). Messy in any event.