# Is there some way to set a window's focus without changing its relative zorder?

Tags: windows, winapi, autohotkey

There is a bug in an application (IntelliJ IDEA) where it fails to honour focus follows mouse (X-mouse).  When I move the mouse on top of IntelliJ, it flashes the window.  I figure I could capture the flashing and just force it to have focus.  Tried this using AHK.  It almost worked (got the `RegisterShellHookWindow` to work and it would run the call back message), but I couldn't give the window focus using `SetFocus`, presumably because I was in a different process space?  I've tried some other ways to give the window focus, but all seem to raise the window, which isn't acceptable.

Is there some manner which I could force a window to capture focus in a different process space or is this not possible due to some security restrictions?

Here is the AHK code (with debugging statements) if anyone is interested (though it doesn't have to be written in AHK):

```ahk
; Register shell hook to detect flashing windows.
DllCall("RegisterShellHookWindow", "Ptr", A_ScriptHwnd)
OnMessage(DllCall("RegisterWindowMessage", "Str", "SHELLHOOK"), "ShellEvent")

FHex( int, pad=0 ) { ; Function by [VxE]. Formats an integer (decimals are truncated) as hex.
  ; "Pad" may be the minimum number of digits that should appear on the right of the "0x".
  Static hx := "0123456789ABCDEF"
  If !( 0 < int |= 0 )
    Return !int ? "0x0" : "-" FHex( -int, pad )
  s := 1 + Floor( Ln( int ) / Ln( 16 ) )
  h := SubStr( "0x0000000000000000", 1, pad := pad < s ? s + 2 : pad < 16 ? pad + 2 : 18 )
  u := A_IsUnicode = 1
  Loop % s
    NumPut( *( &hx + ( ( int & 15 ) << u ) ), h, pad - A_Index << u, "UChar" ), int >>= 4
  Return h
}

FlashWindowEx(hWnd := 0, dwFlags := 0, uCount := 0, dwTimeout := 0) {
   Static A64 := (A_PtrSize = 8 ? 4 : 0) ; alignment for pointers in 64-bit environment
   Static cbSize := 4 + A64 + A_PtrSize + 4 + 4 + 4 + A64
   VarSetCapacity(FLASHWINFO, cbSize, 0) ; FLASHWINFO structure
   Addr := &FLASHWINFO
   Addr := NumPut(cbSize,    Addr + 0, 0,   "UInt")
   Addr := NumPut(hWnd,      Addr + 0, A64, "Ptr")
   Addr := NumPut(dwFlags,   Addr + 0, 0,   "UInt")
   Addr := NumPut(uCount,    Addr + 0, 0,   "UInt")
   Addr := NumPut(dwTimeout, Addr + 0, 0,   "Uint")
   Return DllCall("User32.dll\FlashWindowEx", "Ptr", &FLASHWINFO, "UInt")
}

SetFocus(HWND) {
   HPREV := HWND
   While (HPREV := DllCall("User32.dll\GetWindow", "Ptr", HPREV, "UInt", 3, "UPtr")) ; GW_HWNDPREV = 3
      If DllCall("User32.dll\IsWindowVisible", "Ptr", HPREV, "UInt")
         Break
   WinActivate, ahk_id %HWND%
   If (HPREV)
      DllCall("User32.dll\SetWindowPos", "Ptr", HWND, "Ptr", HPREV, "Int", 0, "Int", 0, "Int", 0, "Int", 0, "UInt", 0x0B)
}

ShellEvent(wParam, lParam) {
    _wParam := FHex(wParam)
    _lParam := FHex(lParam)
    X := 0
    Y := 0
    MouseGetPos, X, Y
    
    ToolTip % "1: (" . X . ", " . Y . ") Trying to activate " . _wParam . ", " . _lParam . ".", (X+1), (Y+1),1 
    if (wParam = 0x8006) ; HSHELL_FLASH
    {   ; lParam contains the ID of the window which flashed:
        FlashWindowEx(lParam)
        ;WinActivate, ahk_id %lParam%
        ;SetFocus(lParam)
        DLLCall("User32.dll\SetFocus", "Ptr", lParam, "Ptr")
        ToolTip % "2: (" . X . ", " . Y . ") Trying to activate " _wParam . ", " . _lParam . ".", (X+1), (Y+21),2
    }
}
```

Comment: `but I couldn't give the window focus using SetFocus, presumably because I was in a different process space`  `SetFocus` will also raise the window.

Comment: `Is there some manner which I could force a window to capture focus in a different process space` By using the AttachThreadInput function, a thread can attach its input processing to another thread. This allows a thread to call SetFocus to set the keyboard focus to a window attached to another thread's message queue

Comment: It seems that there is no way to set the keyboard focus without changing the z-order, related: [Focus a window without changing z-order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24765974/focus-a-window-without-changing-z-order)

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT, maybe there is a way to determine global z-order then?  Does SetWindowPos even work for setting a window's global relative z-order?  I would think that would be kinda weird.

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT, maybe this is just a Window's window manager restriction?

Comment: These windows are ordered according to their appearance on the screen. The topmost window receives the highest rank and is the first window in the Z order.

Comment: AHK is similar to keyboard emulation. Your goal is similar to using `SendInput` to give a keystroke to a specific window, but you don't want to change the Z-Order of the window (become the foreground window). IMHO, until now, I did not find a feasible solution.